# Stuck on proof and need help to solve it

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, problem-solving

1. This is not homework
2. I do it for fun.

I am using the SD system.

**Derive $L\supset T$**

1. $L\supset\left ( C\vee T \right ).$ Assume
2. $\left ( \sim L\vee B \right )\wedge\left ( \sim B\vee\sim C \right ).$ Assume

As we see from the image it is valid in SL truth tree form

[image: Truth tree]

There does not seem to be an easy way to derive it. I figure the the easiest method is to derive a contradiction, but how to do it after the initial set up ?

4. $\sim\left ( L\supset T \right ).$ Assume

For "$Q$" and "$\sim Q$" from #2, we could use $B$ and $\sim B,$ but how to separate them so they could be used ?

Any help would greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Please use mathjax rather than images. This [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good start.

Comment: I tried,it was too messy.

Comment: Natural deduction: assume $L$. With it derive $C \lor T$ and then $\lor$-elimination (Proof by Cases).

Comment: Can l assume the info off the tableaux is the way to go

Comment: @Homer If your goal is to eventually write mathematical proofs, you really should use some form of natural deduction. AFAIK no one outside of philosophy departments uses the tableaux format. Google: software to learn basic methods of proof.

Comment: That was just to show it was valid. As my title states l am having problems doing it. People use SD and SD+. I am using the Logic Book by  Bergman @Dan Christensen l know the basic method of proofs. I thought I could get hints off it

Comment: Start with your given assumptions. Assume L. Use $P\to Q ~\equiv \neg P \lor Q$ to make a chain of implications to obtain T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof by contradiction for this one will be more work than doing a conditional proof, i.e. start a subproof, assume $L$, try to get to $T$, end the subproof, and perform a Conditional Introduction to get $L \supset T$

The rest of this proof is doing the Disjunctive Syllogism pattern over and over. So, if you have the Disjunctive Syllogism rule from SD+ this should actually be quite straightforward:

\begin{array}{lll}
1. & L \supset (C \lor T) & Assumption\\
2. & (\sim L \lor B) \& (\sim B \lor \sim C) & Assumption\\
3. & \quad L & Assumption\\
4. & \quad \sim L \lor B & \& \ Elimination \ Premise \ 2\\
5. & \quad \sim \sim L & Double \ Negation \ 3\\
6. & \quad B & Disjunctive \ Syllogism \ 4, 5\\
13. & \quad ...\\
? & \quad T\\
?+1 & L \supset T & \supset \ Introduction \ 3-?\\
\end{array}

In SD this will be a lot more tedious., but I'll show you how to do one of these. In particular, once you have assumed $L$ as part of your conditional proof, you should be able to get to $B$ using $\sim L \lor B$:

\begin{array}{lll}
1. & L \supset (C \lor T) & Assumption\\
2. & (\sim L \lor B) \& (\sim B \lor \sim C) & Assumption\\
3. & \quad L & Assumption\\
4. & \quad \sim L \lor B & \& \ Elimination \ Premise \ 2\\
5. & \quad \quad \sim L & Assumption\\
6. & \quad \quad \quad \sim B & Assumption\\
7. & \quad \quad \quad L & Reiteration \ 3\\ 
8. & \quad \quad \quad \sim L & Reiteration \ 5\\ 
9. & \quad \quad B & \sim \ Elimination \ 6-8\\
10. & \quad \quad B \ & Assumption\\
11. & \quad \quad B \ & Reiteration \ 10\\
12. & \quad B & \lor \ Elimination \ 4, 5-9,10-11\\
13. & \quad ...\\
? & \quad T\\
?+1 & L \supset T & \supset \ Introduction \ 3-?\\
\end{array}

Comment: @Homer To isolate ~LvB from the second premise you use *conjunction* elimination.  And you also use conjunctive elimination to isolate ~Bv~C. You need this once you have gotten B to get ~C.  And you then combine ~C with CvT (which of course you get form the assumption L and the first premise to get to T, completing the conditional proof.

Comment: How to get B from ~LvB ? You would use DIsjunction Elim. ? To get ~B use ~B V ~ C

Comment: You get B using L and ~LvB ... In the first proof I show how to do this in SD+:  double negate the L to get ~~L, and then use Disjunctive syllogism on ~~L and ~LvB

Comment: In the second proof I show how to do this in SD .. which is a lot more tedious.  In fact, please allow me a comment: these proofs seem to be quite new to you ... so I would recommend sticking to SD+ for now.

Comment: That is the next section in the book. This is the last proof in SD. I didn’t have to many problems with the previous sections but then again the exercises were easy. This one l had to translate it into SL which you see and now l have to prove it.

Comment: Whoever thought that a tiny theorem would have such huge derivation?

Comment: @Homer  Ha ha, yes, in SD it does ... but in SD+ it is a lot shorter, thanks to Disjunctive Syllogism. Which is why it is surprising that you have to use SD before SD+ ... it's like learning to program in machine code before C++.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Start with your given assumptions. Assume L. Use $P\to Q ~\equiv \neg P \lor Q$ to make a chain of implications to obtain T from L.